# is 'ㄹ' from 'ㅌ' in korean creation?

Tags: grammar, hangul

[image]

I have read [an article of how the Korean letters were created](https://www.urimal.org/m/615), and according to that article, Korean consonants are created with the mechanism of "가획", which is making letters by adding a line to the main 5 letters, "ㄱ, ㄴ, ㅁ, ㅅ, ㅇ"
but, how come "ㄹ" is created from "ㅌ"? I don't think adding lines to "ㅌ" won't make "ㄹ", and "ㄹ" doesn't seem to be made by adding a line to any of the letters above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd call that B.S. So you're right. ㄹ does not come from ㅌ.

The creator of those letters clearly stated the point in 훈민정음 written in the year 1445.

https://ko.wikisource.org/wiki/%ED%9B%88%EB%AF%BC%EC%A0%95%EC%9D%8C#%E5%88%B6%E5%AD%97%E8%A7%A3

> - 初聲凡十七字。
> - 牙音ㄱ，象舌根閉喉之形。
> - 舌音ㄴ，象舌附上腭之形。
> - 脣音ㅁ，象口形。
> - 齒音ㅅ，象齒形。
> - 喉音ㅇ，象喉形。
> - ㅋ比ㄱ，聲出稍厲，故加畫。
> - ㄴ而ㄷ，ㄷ而ㅌ，ㅁ而ㅂ，ㅂ而ㅍ，ㅅ而ㅈ，ㅈ而ㅊ，ㅇ而ㆆ，ㆆ而ㅎ，其因聲加畫之義皆同，而唯ㆁ為異。
> - **`半舌音ㄹ，半齒音ㅿ，亦象舌齒之形而異其體，無加劃之義焉。`**

- 초성은 무릇 열 일곱자이다.
- 아음 ㄱ은 혀뿌리가 목구멍을 막는 모양을 본뜨고,
- 설음 ㄴ은 혀가 위턱(윗잇몸)에 붙는 모양을 본뜨고,
- 순음 ㅁ은 입모양을 본뜨고,
- 치음 ㅅ은 이빨 모양을 본뜨고,
- 후음 ㅇ은 목구멍 모양을 본떴다.
- ㅋ은 ㄱ에 비해 소리가 세게 나는 까닭으로 획을 더하였다.
- ㄴ에서 ㄷ, ㄷ에서 ㅌ, ㅁ에서 ㅂ, ㅂ에서 ㅍ, ㅅ에서 ㅈ, ㅈ에서 ㅊ, ㅇ에서 ㆆ, ㆆ에서 ㅎ으로도, 그 - 소리를 바탕으로 획을 더한 뜻은 모두 같으나, 오직 ㆁ만은 달리 했다.
- **`반혓소리 ㄹ, 반잇소리 ㅿ도 또한 혀와 이의 모양을 본떴으나 그 모양새를 달리해서, 획을 더한 뜻은 없다.`**